# KeyError pops up each time a function is called

Tags: python, keyerror, siamese-network, numpy-random

Hi I am trying to implement the Siamese Neural Network for one-shot image recognition with the Omniglot dataset. The initial step for the implementation requires to generate pair samples with same/distinct classes, for that I use the ***make_pair*** function from [Ben Myara's github](https://github.com/bainjamain/pytorch-examples/blob/master/notebooks/1_NeuralNetworks/9_siamese_nn.ipynb) with little modifications. However, the keyError pops up every time when I call the function, so I want to know what causes this error, Here is my implementation:

```
import requests
import io
def load_numpy_arr_from_url(url):
"""
Loads a numpy array from surfdrive. 

Input:
url: Download link of dataset 

Outputs:
dataset: numpy array with input features or labels
"""

response = requests.get(url)
response.raise_for_status()

return np.load(io.BytesIO(response.content)) 



# Downloading may take a while..
train_x    =load_numpy_arr_from_url('https://surfdrive.surf.nl/files/index.php/s/tvQmLyY7MhVsADb/download')
#Transform bool type to integer
train_data = train_x* 1
train_y = load_numpy_arr_from_url('https://surfdrive.surf.nl/files/index.php/s/z234AHrQqx9RVGH/download')

import torch
def make_pairs(data, labels, num=1000):
    digits = {}
    for i, j in enumerate(labels):
        if not j in digits:
            digits[j] = []
        digits[j].append(i)

    pairs, labels_ = [], []
    for i in range(num):
        if np.random.rand() >= .5: # same digit
            digit = random.choice(range(len(labels+1)))
            d1, d2 = random.choice(digits[digit], size=2, replace=False)
            labels_.append(1)
        else:
            digit1, digit2 = np.random.choice(range(len(labels+1)), size=2, replace=False)
            d1, d2 = random.choice(digits[digit1]), np.random.choice(digits[digit2])
            labels_.append(0)
        pairs.append(torch.from_numpy(np.concatenate([data[d1,:], data[d2,:]])).view(1, 56, 28))
  

  
    return torch.cat(pairs), torch.LongTensor(labels_)
```

The error occurs when I try to call the function with the following command:

```
make_pairs(train_data,train_y, 5)
```

Here is the traceback error I got:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-7d53181e46ef> in <module>()
     25 
     26     return torch.cat(pairs), torch.LongTensor(labels_)
---> 27 make_pairs(train_data,train_y, 5)
     28 #print(a)

<ipython-input-30-7d53181e46ef> in make_pairs(data, labels, num)
     14         if np.random.rand() >= .5: # same digit
     15             digit = random.choice(range(len(labels+1)))
---> 16             print(random.choice(digits[digit], replace=False))
     17             d1, d2 = random.choice(digits[digit], size=2, replace=False)
     18             labels_.append(1)

KeyError: 12803
```

Moreover, I have also trying to implement part of the function without the for loop and everything seems to works properly there:

```
import numpy as np
digits = {}
for i, j in enumerate(train_y):
    if not j in digits:
        digits[j] = []
    digits[j].append(i)
pairs, labels_ = [], []
digit = np.random.choice(range(len(train_y)+1)
d1, d2 = np.random.choice(digits[digit], size=2, replace=False)
labels_.append(1)
print(torch.from_numpy(np.concatenate([train_data[d1,:], train_data[d2,:]])).view(1, 56, 28))
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the full error+traceback. You should also take the opportunity to fix the indentation of the code.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Thanks for the feedback, I have edited the content by adding the full error+traceback. In the meanwhile, I have already found the cause of the problem, so I would indicate in the title as well.

Comment: If you have already solve the problem, consider a [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: Yes, I will elaborate on that.

Comment: If you have solved this problem, please add your solution below as an answer